# How do most sync programs monitor file changes?

Tags: sync, dropbox, diff

Do sync programs like Dropbox typically track file changes by doing byte by byte comparisons, or using hashes, or using `diff` / keeping local commit logs like version control, or what?

Comment: This is a little too broad for Superuser.com. Search over on programmers.stackexchange.com for this sort of theoretical question.

Comment: The method will vary depending on the program. What you are asking for at worst is for people to express their opinions about how they think these programs might work (since it is unlikely that the dropbox team or some similar group would see it and post here). And at best for several competing answers that would essentially a list of methods. Neither result fits well with superuser's intended goal.

Comment: "Most sync programs"... I doubt *anyone* can answer this.

Comment: Could you help me move my question to programmers.stackexchange.com in addition to closing my question?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/8/en) it is stated that they perform a "binary diff" to determine what to transfer.

Comment: Thanks, dude! I wouldn't have known where to look for that tidbit.